# Reset index without multiple headers after pivot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'store':[1,1,1,2],'upc':[11,22,33,11],'sales':[14,16,11,29]})
```

which gives this output

```
   store  upc  sales
0      1   11     14
1      1   22     16
2      1   33     11
3      2   11     29
```

I want something like this

```
store upc_11  upc_22  upc_33
    1   14.0    16.0    11.0
    2   29.0    NaN     NaN
```

I tried this

```
newdf = df.pivot(index='store', columns='upc')
newdf.columns = newdf.columns.droplevel(0)
```

and the output looks like this with multiple headers

```
upc      11    22    33
store                  
1      14.0  16.0  11.0
2      29.0   NaN   NaN
```

I also tried

```
newdf = df.pivot(index='store', columns='upc').reset_index()
```

This also gives multiple headers

```
    store sales            
upc          11    22    33
0       1  14.0  16.0  11.0
1       2  29.0   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try via fstring+columns attribute and list comprehension:

```
newdf = df.pivot(index='store', columns='upc')
newdf.columns=[f"upc_{y}" for x,y in newdf.columns]
newdf=newdf.reset_index()
```

OR

In 2 steps:

```
newdf = df.pivot(index='store', columns='upc').reset_index()
newdf.columns=[f"upc_{y}" if y!='' else f"{x}" for x,y in newdf.columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, which is longer than @Anurag's:

```
(df.pivot(index='store', columns='upc')
.droplevel(axis=1, level=0)
.rename(columns = lambda df: f"upc_{df}")
.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
 
   upc_11  upc_22  upc_33
1    14.0    16.0    11.0
2    29.0     NaN     NaN
```